# How can i get count of (5th and 20th day ) between two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can i get count of (5th and 20th day ) between two dates in sql

For example  if from date is 05/05/2013 and to date is 20/07/2013

Result is : 5

Comment: Include a tag for which RDMS you're using.

Comment: pls provide some examples!

Comment: I think the question is: how often do the 5th and the 20th occur between given dates.

Comment: On the calendar. Not in the table.

Comment: No table, need to get it from calender

Comment: Since there seem to be 6 5ths and 20ths between `05/05/2013` and `20/07/2013`, but you've specified 5, this suggests that one of these endpoints is meant to be considered *exclusive* rather than *inclusive*. If that's so, which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @dtfrom  as Datetime, @dtTo as Datetime

select @dtFrom = cast('5/5/2013' as datetime), @dtTo = cast('07/20/2013' as datetime)

;with dates(selectedDate,selectedday) as(
select @dtfrom,Day(@dtfrom)
 union All
select DateAdd(day,1,selectedDate), day(DateAdd(day,1,selectedDate)) from dates  where selectedDate < @dtTo
)

select Count(*) from dates  where selectedday in(5,20)
```

Comment: I have included from and to date, so, count is 6 not five. please change your condition accordingly

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: Hi jord, here I have used common table expression. You can find out more about common table expression in google with search term (CTS in Sql server). with CTS you don't have to make table. Sql server auotmatically make table structure in memory and you can use one time this table after defining but after that it will be automatically distroyed from memory and you will not be able to access.

Comment: Also, we have a better facility from 2005 that is recursion in sql server.  you can make recursion in sql server with (CTS + Union all). Please search about it and if you have any query you can write, i will surely help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM your_table
 WHERE DATEPART('d', date_column) IN (5, 20)
   AND date_column BETWEEN '01/01/2013' and '30/12/2013'
```

Where `01/01/2013` and `30/12/2013` are your range.